# animate image from P1.x,y to Pn.x,y using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, math, animation, canvas

My goal is to point at different places within the screen, store those points (x, y), and make my image animate through all the stored X and Y values.

I store everything using arrays. Here is part of the code:

```
function storeCoordinates(e){
    pos.push({x:e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY });

    if(pos.length > 1){
        delta.push({
            dx: pos[pos.length - 1].x - pos[pos.length - 2].x,
            dy: pos[pos.length - 1].y - pos[pos.length - 2].y
        });
        //Distance between the two points
        distance[distance.length - 2] = Math.sqrt(delta[delta.length - 2].dx * delta[delta.length - 2].dx + delta[delta.length - 2].dy * delta[delta.length - 2].dy);

        moves[moves.length - 2] = distance[distance.length - 2] / speed;

        xunits[xunits.length - 2] =  (pos[pos.length - 1].x - pos[pos.length - 2].x) / moves[moves.length - 2];
        yunits[yunits.length - 2] = (pos[pos.length - 1].y - pos[pos.length - 2].y) / moves[moves.length - 2];
    }
}                                                      
c.addEventListener('click', function(e){storeCoordinates(e);}, false);
```

But the animation never starts. Any help would be much appreciated!

[**Full fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/djt6V/17/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your existing code.

Here's a refactored demo of your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9EZha/

**About some refactoring to your code:**

You can get mouse position relative to the canvas like this:

```
var mouseX=e.clientX-offsetX;
var mouseY=e.clientY-offsetY;
```

To animate along your multiple click-points, you need to break each line down into points along the line.

You can create a poly-point line from your "pos" array like this:

```
function makePolyPoints(pathArray){

    var points=[];
    for(var i=1;i<pathArray.length;i++){
        var startPt=pathArray[i-1];
        var endPt=pathArray[i];
        var dx = endPt.x-startPt.x;
        var dy = endPt.y-startPt.y;
        for(var n=0;n<=100;n++){
            var x= startPt.x + dx * n/100;
            var y= startPt.y + dy * n/100;
            points.push({x:x,y:y});
        }
    }
    return(points);
}
```

Your animate function should:

- determine if another loop is required (or if the image has completed its animation)
- If there's more animation to do, request another animation frame.
- draw your image at the current position on your polyline.
- increment to the next position along your polyline.

Here's what a typical animation loop might look like:

```
function animate(){

    // are we done animating?

    if(polyPos>polyline.length-1){return;}

    // request another animation frame

    requestAnimFrame(animate);

    // determine the current point on the polyline

    var pt=polyline[polyPos];

    // draw the image at the current point

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.drawImage(car, pt.x, pt.y);

    // increment the next position on the polyline 
    // for the next animation frame

    polyPos++;
}
```

Comment: I realised some of my issues and fixed them, and made the car move from one point to another - still ,this is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Just one question: in your makePolyPoints function there is a for loop which goes to 100. What good does that do? I tried putting 50 there instead and the car moved faster. I don't see why...

Comment: 100 is an arbitrary number of points that the car will travel on each line--one point per animation loop.  So yes, if you reduce the points to travel, the car will move faster, and if you increase the points to travel, the car will move slower. Think of it this way, 100 points means the car will take 100 animation frames to complete the line.  If instead you complete the line in 50 animation frames, the car will complete faster--it will go faster.

Comment: Thank you :) I recently orderer the HTML canvas book from Amazon. It can't get here fast enough...